# ZIO Test TestAspect: Avoid @@ to all test

Tags: scala, zio, zio-test

In this sample code, I have 2 Specs, and I want to do some before action to both of them, then I have to call @@ TestAspect.before to both test. If the number of tests increase, add @@ TestAspect to all test/suite sounds not a good idea, how to avoid this?

```scala
import zio._
import zio.test._
import zio.test.Assertion._


object WorldSpec extends ZIOSpecDefault {   
  def spec = suite("HelloWorldSpec")(
    test("simple test") {
      assertTrue(1 + 1 == 2)
    }   
  ) @@ TestAspect.before(
      doBeforeFunctions   
  ) 
}


object UniverseSpec extends ZIOSpecDefault {   
  def spec = suite("HelloUniverseSpec")(
    test("sayHello correctly displays output") {
     assertTrue(2 + 2 == 4)
    }
  ) @@ TestAspect.before(
      doBeforeFunction   
  ) 
}
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine to repeat yourself in tests. A test should be easy to read without too much magic or stuff coming from another file/class.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could always do old-good-subclassing if you wanted to ...

```
abstract class MySpec { 

   def actualSpec:  Spec[TestEnvironment with Scope, Any]
   override def spec = actualSpec @@ before(doBeforeFunction)
}
```

But ... why? At this point, it seems like writing `@@ before` in every spec is almost less effort, and in no time, you are going to diverge more anyway ...

Comment: Thanks @Dima, it's a workable solution. I agree that just writing @@before is the most easy solution. But I'm refactoring thousands of test and writing @@ Aspect to all tests is not desirable for me. That why I'm trying to encapsulate them to abstract class, other test just need to be extends when defining.

Comment: For anyone see this question later, another possible solution is override aspects, similar to this:
https://gitlab.com/leadiq-oss/reactivemongo-zio/-/blame/series/2.x/reactivemongo-zio/src/test/scala/zio/mongo/MongoITSpec.scala#L13